# how to define reserved template for python file for eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, ide, pydev

I need to use a `default template` for my files, such as first heading : description of file, author, `shebang line` and so on. But `PyDev` and `eclipse` don't do it for me.

When i want to create a new file in my project, how i have them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define the templates used in PyDev (both for code-completion and for new modules) in window > preferences > pydev > editor > templates.

Anything with the context 'new module' there will be shown to you when you create a new module (and you can have many templates, such as one for unittests, empty modules, class modules, etc).

Note that the templates are only presented when you create a module with Alt+Shift+N > pydev module (or file > new > pydev module), not when you create a regular 'file' (even if it ends with .py)